# Are there free cloud computing platforms for biology projects?

Tags: fastq, genomics, phylogenetics, sratoolkit

I want to implement the analysis found in the paper [RNA-Seq of Tumor-Educated Platelets Enables Blood-Based Pan-Cancer, Multiclass, and Molecular Pathway Cancer Diagnostics](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26525104) The project id is [281708](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/bioproject/?term=PRJNA281708). It has 285 samples comprising about 300 Gb of read data. The reads are available on [sra](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/bioproject/?term=PRJNA281708).

I want to apply a machine-learning pipeline to find important features in these data but I do not have access to computing resources to finish the project.

### Question

Are there free cloud computing platforms that I can use to perform this research?

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes it is duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting started with a project and need some free computational resources you should look at https://galaxyproject.org/. There are some free servers that you may be able to use. However, Galaxy is designed to have pre-fabricated pipelines and a GUI to avoid having to deal with command-line tools. Therefore any sort of custom analysis will have to go through the [galaxy API](https://galaxyproject.org/develop/api/).

Otherwise, most of the free computational resources that were available several years ago like iPlantCollaborative are no longer available. Running servers costs money, after all, and the funding for such projects often runs out after a few years.

You may consider asking researchers at your local universities to collaborate and provide you with access to their servers.